# How can I put my logo to right side of the navbar?

Tags: html, css

My header should be `fixed` on the page so i couldn't use `float:right;`. I'm %150 newbie around here. Logo should be  on right side of the navbar and also responsive. I tried `margin`, `float` and other `flex` properties. I'm just going to be mad. Where is the mistake.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.header-logo {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  background: #609F92;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px;
}

#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#nav-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav-bar li {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="header-logo">
        <img id="header-img" src="https://thumbnails-photos.amazon.com/v1/thumbnail/lFJOXJpuTKGgtJYa9-wScA?viewBox=943%2C943&ownerId=A4PYAHHROL8LR&groupShareToken=OSTx_M1GRRS1y_rPWtVfGA.8mpQdgJWAet53NrSPN2TyS">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks like it works as intended? check: https://jsfiddle.net/pgz09u5w/

Comment: I want it to stick to the right (I mean the logo)

Comment: you mean to the far right of the available window?

Comment: yes. i want it to be stick on the right side. and it wont go anywhere even if the width of the page changes.

Comment: Do you want your logo to resize as the screen does as well? Or do you want it to be the same size whichever screen size you're on?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mainly caused because you nesting so many flexboxes within each other. As such the elements will not span the entire available width automatically.

1. Give the `nav` tag a width of 100% to fill out the entire containers width: `#nav-bar { width: 100% }`
2. to align the logo to the right within a flexbox use margin-left: auto: `.header-logo { margin-left: auto; }`

Also you could improve your code by removing the ID from the `nav` element and target the `nav` element directly. As semantically you should only have one `nav` element it would be unecessary to asign an id to it. Same rule also counts for the `header` element.
Then you could remove `display: flex;` from the header which has only one child element in the first place and as such is useless. IMHO it would be smarter though to close the `nav` with the `ul` as the logog is semantically not part of the `navbar`.
Last but not least you could remove `flex-direction: row` as it is the default value anyways.

```css
#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
}

.header-logo {
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* original CSS */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.header-logo {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  background: #609F92;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px;
}

#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#nav-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav-bar li {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="header-logo">
        <img id="header-img" src="https://thumbnails-photos.amazon.com/v1/thumbnail/lFJOXJpuTKGgtJYa9-wScA?viewBox=943%2C943&ownerId=A4PYAHHROL8LR&groupShareToken=OSTx_M1GRRS1y_rPWtVfGA.8mpQdgJWAet53NrSPN2TyS">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

I also created a Codepen for you where I corrected the code to be semantically correct and to shroten it to the necessary lines: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/LYOgRKX)